# For each $_POST variable a mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: sql, post, foreach, code-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

For my school homework I have to create a **function** that uses `trim()`, `htmlspecialchars()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL- and HTML injection.

I've been trying for a while but I can't get it to work. I've tried a `foreach` loop and an `extract` function. I must be doing something wrong, or missing something.

So far, I've got this: (just to see if the variables are being processed)

`foreach ($_Post as $Key => $Value) {
$$Key = $Value;
echo $$Key."<br>";
}`

But it won't return anything.

I can use the `trim` etc on every variable on its own, but there must be a much easier way.

I've got the `$_POST` variables 'voorletters', 'tussenvoegsel', 'naam', 'adres', 'huisnummer' (numbers), 'telefoon' (numbers), 'postcode', 'woonplaats', 'geslacht', 'email' and 'wachtwoord' (password).

Please help me :(! I'm a beginner concerning php, so please try to explain thoroughly.

Comment: why you trying to set the key equal to the value?

Comment: I want to have it this way:
$_POST['voorletters'] = "imput" 
gives eventually:
$voorletters = "imput"; 

With the security checks ofcourse..

Comment: a very simple solution could be this: `foreach($_POST as &$val) $val = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($val)));` ..it passes any post value by reference and mask/escape it.

Comment: I'd expect schools to teach prepared statements rather than a legacy API that's basically discontinued...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use foreach and mysqli\_real\_escape\_string for many post value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952706/use-foreach-and-mysqli-real-escape-string-for-many-post-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Current value in $_POST["' . $key . '"] is : ' . $value . '<br>';
    $_POST[$key] = your_filter($value);
}
```

where `your_filter()` is your function calling trim, htmlspecialchars, etc. :

```
function your_filter($value) {
    $newVal = trim($value);
    $newVal = htmlspecialchars($newVal);
    $newVal = mysql_real_escape_string($newVal);
    return $newVal;
}
```

Pay attention to the variable name too which is `$_POST` not `$_Post`.
You don't need to use $$ here, you have the key name in the loop in `$key` and you can access/replace the value in the array with `$_POST[$key]`

EDIT : added an echo to print current value

EDIT2 : added an example of `your_filter()` function

Comment: Okay, when having to apply multiple filters, can I do it like this?

`foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Current value in $_POST["' . $key . '"] is : ' . $value . '<br>';
    $_POST[$key] = trim($value);
 $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
 $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}`

Comment: No because doing this you don't change $value so you will only store the result of mysql_real_escape_string($value);. I updated my answer to show a function to do what you want. You can also do it directly in a foreach

Comment: Okay. How can I get the $_POST variables in variables like $voorletters (from $_POST['voorletters']) ?

Comment: you would do what you were trying to do in your question : `$$key = your_filter($value);` but why would you need to do that?

Comment: So I can get all the variables to be saved in the database, with this line:

`$query="INSERT INTO klant VALUES ('$klantnummer', '$voorletters', '$tussenvoegsel', '$naam', '$adres', '$huisnummer', '$postcode', '$woonplaats', '$geslacht', '$telefoon', '$email', '$wachtwoord',  '$datumin', '$status')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Ok. so `$$key = your_filter($value);` will work but it really is not a proper way to insert data in your database. You should check Mysqli extension. But if your homework is written like this I guess it's not your fault.

Comment: Well, I see everytime I search something on php.net, there is an error that mysql statements are discontinued or something? But we have to work with mysql at my school, not mysqli. The school's fault I guess, haha.

But thanks a lot! You've really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

```
// $_POST = array('voorletters' => '<<', 'tussenvoegsel' => '>>', 'naam' => '<<');

foreach($_POST as &$val) //pass any post value by reference
   $val = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(trim($val)));


extract($_POST);
echo $voorletters;
echo $tussenvoegsel;
echo $naam;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($_POST as $Key => $Value) { 

 echo yourFunctionName($Value)."<br/>"; 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try This...

```
function real_escape_and_trim($value)
{
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    return $value;
}

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $_POST[$key] = real_escape_and_trim($value);
}

$field_name = $_POST['field_name'];
```