# Use foreach and mysqli_real_escape_string for many post value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a page that collect many data and i need to escape those data before made a sql query insert into db.

I write this before the SQL query :

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) $_POST[$k] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$v);
```

My $conn is :

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');
```

Still work but i'm not sure if it's safe.

Comment: This should be OK, but it would be better if you used parametrized queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **extremely wrong way** of dealing with POST variables.
Wrong in so many ways.

And surely it is not safe.

depends on the way you are going to use POST data in the query, this code could be corrected or could be unusable and unsafe at all.

As Barmar said, you ought to use prepared statements. Better if you have a prepared statement for the insert data too.

Comment: I like how your name is Your common Sense :-)

Comment: can you explain more, how could it be unsafe?

Comment: in so many ways to list them all here. Strictly speaking, tha function you have fancy to use **has absolutely nothing to do with whatever safety.**

Comment: ok so you mean mysqli_real_escape_string is bad for safety, for example against XSS attacks. I do use binding, but was just asking if you meant if the foreach way is bad, or the mysqli_escape_string. thanks for the explanation

Comment: It is not "bad". It's just inapplicable for the safety matters.

Comment: if you are using binding, then using mysqli_real_escape_string makes absolutely no sense

Comment: I don't use the escape_string haven't used it since long, was just asking to know what exactly are you talking about.

Comment: I see, just confused you with the OP. Well, the answer is simple, nowhere (beside some ignorant articles) it is said that mysqli_real_escape_string has any relation to whatever safety or security. And indeed it is. So, it should never be used by the means of any protection, despite of any superstitions shared by PHP users.

Comment: Well It is great to speak about how bad a script is but it does not advance any of here looking for solutions- Isn't what this website is for solution? Even an example of a better script- With comparison to a bad script will work- and how about "addslashes"

Answer (score 2):

this should be safe.

```
$query=$conn->prepare("select * from yourtable where colum= ? and column2 = ? ");
$query->bind_param('ss', $_POST['var1'],$_POST['var2'] );
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz');

$ARR_DATA = array();
foreach($_POST as $k => $v) 
{
   $ARR_DATA[$k] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$v); // store your escaped value in $ARR_DATA
}
```

Now you can use `$ARR_DATA` values instead of using `$_POST` wherever you want.

Comment: Please refrain form posting dangerous and injection-prone code, thank you.

Comment: what is dangerous in it?

Comment: Would you please refer to other answers on the topic, which was many times answered and discussed already, thank you.